# JavaScript - Split attribute string and append additional text

Tags: javascript, substring

I have the following div, which has a "number" attribute that references an internal document ID.

```
    <div class="container" number="+905423871416  +905423871416"></div>
    <div class="container" number="+905423871416></div>
```

With JavaScript/jQuery, I can add add the text ".ID" to the end of the attribute, especially for the second item. The result would look like this: "+905423871416.ID". This is great, and works perfectly well. However, the same approach effects item one slightly differently, producing the following result: "+905423871416  +905423871416.ID".

What I would essentially like to do, is split those individual id numbers and add ".ID" to the end of them, separated by a comma. The result I would ideally like would be the following:

```
<div class="container" number="+905423871416.ID,  +905423871416.ID"></div>
```

I was using the following:

```
 $('.container').each(function(){
    var number= $(this).attr('number') + '.ID';
  $('#container').append(number);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `split()`, then append an ID suffix and `join()` again.

Answer (score 1):

I think best solution would be to use String.replace() with a regular expression.
Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp for a quick reference and example.

Comment: Please, try to summarize the content of the page you linked, instead of just link it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expresion like this one:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    var number= $(this).attr('number').replace(/(\+\d+)/g, "$1\.ID,").slice(0,-1);
    $('#container').append(number);
});
```

It matches in the string a `+` followed by a sequence of digits and replaces that match by itself followed by `.ID,`
The slice just removes the last comma.

Answer (score 0):

This gets each number attribute, adds .ID to the end of each run of digits, and replaces the number attribute:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    var numberattr= $(this).attr('number');
    numberattr=numberattr.replace(/(\+[0-9]+)/g, "$1.ID");
    $(this).attr('number', numberattr);
});
```

Or more succinctly:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('number', $(this).attr('number').replace(/(\+[0-9]+)/g, "$1.ID"));
});
```